# save form fields as a draft DJANGO

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

1. I need to save data from the form fields into draft, no validation needed yet, i just use ajax POST method to send data into the server.
2. However i will need to retrieve data back from the db on form load. It includes implementation of some *load_draft* function

**AJAX**

```
$('.save-draft').on(click, function() {
var data = {some:$(input[name=data]).val()}
$.ajax({
    url:'save-draft/',
    data: data,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function() {
        alert('success')
    }
});
```

It works well, however i don't quite get what i need to return in my Django *save_draft *function:

**Django**

```
def save_draft(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
         name = request.POST['data']
         try:
             draft = Draft.objects.create(name=name)
             draft.save()
         except:
             pass
    else:
    # Somehow to retrieve data from db here OR is it going into *load_draft* function with its own jQuery? adding adding data into fields

return # JSON object?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should return just simple response including status. It might be done like this:

```
    import json
    from django.http import HttpResponse
...
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps('status': 1), content_type="application/json")
```

To check it on client side.

And I think you need load_draft function, which also return draft instance in json format. You should read it in client side and fill original form by its values.

Comment: so 'status' goes no where just for the browser to check if everything's okay?

Comment: Yes, you can check it in browser to know if draft has been saved correctly.